# Functions such that $f^{(k)}(t)\leq C(k)f(t)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What functions do they comply with  $f^{(k)}(t)\leq C(k)f(t)$ for any $k>0$,  and $t$ enough large, and C(k) constant? Only the exponential function?

Comment: All polynomials with positive leading coefficient.

Comment: Lots of such functions exist. $e^{\sin\,x }$ is one such, $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$ is another one.